# Why are memory leaks reported for Indy 10?

Tags: delphi

I have this leak in Indy 10.5.7 (under Delphi 7).

5 - 12 bytes: TIdThreadSafeInteger x 1
21 - 36 bytes: TIdCriticalSection x 2

---

I use Indy like this:

```
function getWeb(a,b:Integer):Integer;
var url: string;
    H: TIdHttp;
    SS: TStringStream;
begin
  url := 'http://blabla';
  H := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
  try
    SS := TStringStream.Create('');
    try
      H.Get(url, SS);
      Result := StrToInt(SS.DataString);
    FINALLY
     SS.Free;
    END;
  finally H.Free;
  end;
```

The leak itself doesn't bother me since is on app shutdown. That makes my melon explode is the error message I see every time I shut down the app.

Why this leak appear?

---

I have checked the Indy web site but it barely makes sense. Anyway, it looks this bug cannot be fixed: the latest version of Indy cannot be compiled with Delphi 7. The only solution might be Indy 9.
Update: it looks like what on the web site calls  v10.203 is is actually v10.2.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem that occurs with FastMM memory manager and has been around for a while and there is a lot of information available on fixes. The solution I use in Delphi 2010 is:

1. Make the changes below to the file IdGlobal.pas
2. Add the path "C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\source\Indy\Indy10\System" (without quotes) to the library.

Changes:

```
{$IFNDEF DOTNET}
  {$IFDEF REGISTER_EXPECTED_MEMORY_LEAK}
function IndyRegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(AAddress: Pointer): Boolean;
{$IFDEF USEINLINE}inline;{$ENDIF}
begin

  // ===== My modification begins =====================

    Result := FastMM4.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(AAddress);
    Exit;


  // ===== My modification ends =====================
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was [supposedly fixed in the "latest Indy 10 snapshot"](http://atozedsoftware.newsgroups.archived.at/indy.general/200906/0906236411.html) over a year and a half ago. People using the version of Indy that came with their version of Delphi are using out-dated versions and should upgrade.

Comment: Hi Rob. I am using IdAbout.ShowDlg; and it shows that my Indy ver is 10.5.7. There is a version newer than this?

Comment: Hi Brian. My Delphi 7 shows that IndyRegisterExpectedMemoryLeak is not compiled (no blue dots), but the initialization and finalization section do have dots.

Comment: @Altar current Indy version is 10.5.8 (see IdVers.inc)

Comment: @mjn - They have only v10.5.7       -       https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10/tags/

Comment: 10.5.8 is the latest active code located in the Trunk (svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10/trunk). The Tags folder is for finalized releases. 10.5.7 is the version that shipped with XE.

Answer (score 2):

There is a IdStack validation file which does not pass through the cleaning function.

Open the file IdStack.pas

At the end of the file, look for this:

```
{$ IFNDEF DOTNET}  
   {$ IFDEF} REGISTER_EXPECTED_MEMORY_LEAK
      IndyRegisterExpectedMemoryLeak (GStackCriticalSection); 
   {$ ENDIF} 
{$ ENDIF} 

finalization 

    // Dont Free. If shutdown is from another Init section, it can cause GPF When stack 
    // Tries to access it. App will kill it off anyways, so just let it leak 

    // # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
    // THIS LINE AND INCLUDE A COMMENT LINE DOWN 
    if GStackCriticalSection <> nil then FreeAndNil (GStackCriticalSection);
    // # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

    {$ IFDEF} FREE_ON_FINAL 
    // # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
    // FreeAndNil (GStackCriticalSection); // DISABLE THIS LINE
    // # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
    {$ ENDIF} 

    end.
```

I'm using version 10.515 from Indy, you can find this version for download at http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/

Comment: Please don't use signatures, taglines, or other such information in your posts here. Everything you post has your name in the lower right corner, and you have your entire profile to tell people who you are, what your hobbies are, and anything else you'd like them to know about you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to remove other message includes this command in the main DPR

```
Application.terminate; 
if GThreadCount <> Nil then GThreadCount.Free;
```

Add IdThread uses.

Even more!